# Whether to transform non-normal variables prior to performing EM imputation?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, data-imputation

I recently received the following email:

> I have  a sample of 100 and approximately 6-7% missing data on each independent variable of interest, and non-normally distributed IVs.  I have square root transformed  the non-normal IVs so I could use EM imputation in SPSS to impute missing data.  I then back transformed the variables by squaring them.

#### Questions

- Is it necessary to make variables normally distributed in order to use EM imputation either in SPSS or in general?
- Does it make sense then to back transform variables after imputation?

Answer (score 1):

The EM imputation in SPSS uses the Expectation-Maximization Algorithm.
The estimation, by default, assumes that the data are normally distributed. However, you can specify a multivariate t distribution with a specified number of degrees of freedom or a mixed normal distribution with any mixture proportion (PROPORTION) and any standard deviation ratio (LAMBDA).
You can find the syntax specification in the SPSS command syntax reference, MVA.